When the Nestjs program uses StreamableFile to return the stream, the picture cannot be displayed normally
I tried to return the image file stream through StreamableFile according to the example on the official website, but the image could not be displayed normally. The file exists and the path is correct.
Here is my code:
  @Get('/avatar/:userId')
  async showAvatar(
      @Param('userId') userId: number, 
      @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response
  ) :Promise<StreamableFile> {
      const { filename, mimetype } = await this.fileService.queryAvatar(userId);
      const filePath = join(process.cwd(), `${AVATAR_PATH}/${filename}`);
      const file = createReadStream(filePath); 
      const fileStats = await promises.stat(filePath);
      console.log(fileStats.size) // 50365
      res.set({
          'Content-Type': mimetype,  //  'image/jpeg'
          'Content-Length': fileStats.size,  // 396
          'Content-Disposition': 'inline;',
      });
      return new StreamableFile(file);
  }

As mentioned above, fileStats.size is printed as 50365, but fileStats.size is only 396 when set in the headers. I guess this is the reason for data loss.
file.pipe(res);

There is no problem and the image can be displayed normally. I also noticed that doing this the Content-Type is image/jpeg.But StreamableFile is image/jpeg; charset=utf-8.

what if you don't use StreamableFile, ie., stream that file using file.pipe(res)?

file.pipe(res)  is no probrom, but officially not recommended

there's nothing about this being recommended or not, but I got you. I'd suggest you to report this as a bug then
